# XMLSocket send - появляется лишний символ

Tags: java, клиент-сервер, actionscript

Код класса клиента AS 3.0

```
package main
{
    import flash.net.*;
    import flash.events.*;
        public class SocketClient {
            private var hostName:String = "localhost";
            private var port:uint = 4100;
            private var socket:XMLSocket;
    
            public function SocketClient() {
                socket = new XMLSocket();
                configureListeners(socket);
                if (hostName && port) {
                    socket.connect(hostName, port);
                }
            }
    
            public function send(data:Object):void {
                socket.send('<data><viewer_id>1</viewer_id></data>\n');trace('date send: ' + data);
            }
    
            private function configureListeners(dispatcher:IEventDispatcher):void {
                dispatcher.addEventListener(Event.CONNECT, connectHandler);
                dispatcher.addEventListener(DataEvent.DATA, dataHandler);
            }

    
            private function connectHandler(event:Event):void {
                trace("connectHandler: " + event);
            }
    
            private function dataHandler(event:DataEvent):void {
                trace("dataHandler: " + event);
            }

        }
}
```

Код сервера. На JAVA.

```
public void run()
    {
 
        try
        {         
            readerIn = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(ClientSocket.getInputStream()));
            printOut = new PrintStream(ClientSocket.getOutputStream());
            
            String str = null;
            boolean done = false;
            while(!done) {
                str = null;
                System.out.println("Ожидаем прихода сообщения!");
                
                str = readerIn.readLine(); // пока клиент пришлет строку текста.
                if(str == null)
                { 
                    break;
                } 
                
                System.out.println("Пришло : " + str);
                
                
                
                printOut.println("Пришло : " + str); // отсылаем клиенту обратно ту самую строку текста.
                System.out.println("Ожидание следующей строки...");
                
            }
            ClientSocket.close();
            
        }
        catch(Exception error)
        {
            
        }
        System.out.println("Поток закрыт!");
    }
```

Суть проблемы такова. При отправки данных от клиента начиная с второго сообщения перед самим сообщением появляется лишний символ. Вот лог сервера.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Какой код у символа? Наверняка это \r или \n. readerIn.readLine() считает их символами конца строки. Добавь readerIn.skip(1) после readerIn.readLine().

Comment: спс. помогло.

Comment: Оказалось так. что если добавить readerIn.skip(1) то у клиента не срабатывает событие dataHandler.

Comment: код символа 0.

Comment: Странно. Попробуй readerIn.read()

Answer (score 0):

Надо было ещё сделать так . `printOut.println("Пришло : " + str + "\0");`

Comment: ... Зачем?